# CTRL keyCode (17) not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events, addeventlistener, keycode

I have the following code which adds an eventListener to a HTML textarea. It's supposed to console log the keycode which was pressed, and, if the keyCode is == to 17 (CTRL), console log "You pressed CTRL.". For some reason, when I press CTRL in the textarea, it's not console logging the keyCode which was pressed, nor "You pressed CTRL." If I press "A" for example, console log return "97" which is correct. It also works with all other letters.

Here's the code:

```
document.getElementById("msgBox").addEventListener("keypress",function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 17){
        console.log("You pressed CTRL.");
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE : It's also not working with other special keys like "shift, Fx, alt, home etc.

HTML for the textarea :

```
<textarea id="msgBox" placeholder="Enter your message" autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML code of the input field, too, please?

Comment: Added it now. @danielaKay

Comment: I just tried your jsfiddle both in Firefox and Chrome, none of them work. 

??

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I only tested letters, and *that* works with `e.which` :-/ The ctrl key still doesn't work. My bad.

Comment: Yeah, letters do work, I said that in my post :P . Also, it's not working with other special keys, not just ctrl.

Comment: Oh dear. I should go and work on my caffeine levels instead of posting here...

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, special keys do not work with the `keypress` event, but they do with the `keydown` event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead: (e.which == 17)

Comment: Oh, you might have to put this as the first line in your if statement, to prevent the default handler from handling it: e.preventDefault();

Comment: I forgot about that, but that also doesn't work. Also, that prevents users to type in the box.

Comment: Cool! This made me google the intricacies of key events, and ... well, I'll be in my bunk.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the ctrl key: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmez4ur1/1/)

Comment: Interesting, I can't seem to get control to work with the keypress at all, but it works fine with the keydown event.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `e.ctrlKey`.

See the MDN documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey

If you want an easy way to manage keypress you could use a dedicated library like https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/

Comment: @aCodingN00b please post the rest of the code so that we can check whether your HTML is correct.

Comment: Added it in the post.