# Delete button keyCode not working

Tags: javascript, html, keycode

I have a button that I want to be pressed when the user presses the <kbd>del</kbd> key. I have this:

```
document.getElementById('result').onkeypress=function(e){
    //This works, when the user presses enter, submitbtn is clicked
    if(e.keyCode==13){
       document.getElementById('submitbtn').click();
    }

    //This doesn't, but it is the same as the code above
    else if(e.keyCode==46){
        document.getElementById('clrbtn').click();
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<input id="result" type="number" min="0" placeholder="0">
<button id="submitbtn" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<button id="clrbtn" onclick="clr()">Clear</button>
```

I have tried `e.which` and `e.preventDefault()` but neither work. I looked at [CTRL keyCode (17) not working in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207389/ctrl-keycode-17-not-working-in-javascript) and I checked to see if there was a `delKey`, similar to `ctrlKey` but there isn't.
How can I make the delete keyCode, which I am certain is 46, work with my code? Are there any better methods?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your syntax/logic seems right -- can you post your HTML code?

Comment: are you sure it is not `8`

Comment: @epascarello 8 is backspace

Comment: I think you need to use keydown

Comment: what is the element with the id of result ?

Comment: Pretty sure `onkeypress` suppresses the delete key; try changing it to `onkeydown`.

Comment: @FadySadek It is the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitting when you press enter but it does not have to do anything with your code that is why the delete key is not working
you should replace onkeypress with onkeydown

Comment: check this code pen it is working after i made this change http://jsbin.com/qovehexuxo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The input is not in a form, and requires the keyCode to work

Comment: check this change , i have removed the form and it is still working http://jsbin.com/qovehexuxo/edit?html,js,output